# which file in linux machine represent the gcc standard c library?

Tags: c, linux, fedora, glibc, libc

Many places I read that `libc.a` is the gcc standard c library. I could not find it on my system.

My system (fedora 17 - linux on intel 32 chip) has latest `gcc` and following files I could find on the disk in `/usr/lib`:

1. libc.so   (238 bytes)
2. libc-2.15.so   (2 MB)
3. libc_nonshared.a  (20.7 kB)

I checked by using -v -wl,--verbose option that  these are the files linker uses for linking automatically. but there is no such file as libc.a

Is libc.a missing on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was missing on my system since `glibc-static` was not installed. Now I've installed it and I can see `libc.a` in `/usr/lib`.